# Can I redirect HTTPS alarms to nagios

Tags: monitoring, nagios

Our client has numerous servers which configured to send traps to a server where HP Open View is running. From there, after some processing, the alarms are being redirected to NOC (Network Operations Center) using HTTPS protocol. I have to simulate this environment locally in the lab. Specifically I want to set up some kind of system which will function as NOC. After some research in the internet, I have found that **Nagios** seems to be just the solution for me. Do I get it correct? Can I set up Nagios and configure it to receive HTTPS traps and show it? Is this is its purpose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Nagios can handle this - but not out of the box. Nagios handles scheduling of running jobs, escalating and reporting. In this scenario, the job is scheduled elsewhere and the status injected into the monitoring solution. Nagios will happily accomodate this mode of operation ([passive checks](http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/3_0/passivechecks.html) in Nagios terminology) but will require something to sink the message (i.e. an HTTPS server and some application logic) and translate it into something Nagios will understand (a PROCESS_SERVICE_CHECK_RESULT message). The link describes the format of the message.